# jQuery force/trick .scroll() to bubble

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

Is it possible to force or trick the `.scroll()` event to bubble so I can catch the user scrolling a `<div>` with `overflow: auto;` in ajax loaded content? I am loading some HTML via `$.ajax` and need some way to detect as they are scrolling. According to the W3C scroll should not bubble which is why I assume jQuery doesn't do it. However I am able to catch the `$(window).on('scroll', function() { console.log('scrolling'); });`

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/data.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#container").html(data);
        }        
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').on('scroll', '#content', function () {
        console.log('scrolling');
    });
});
```

The `$('#container')` is the container where the loaded `$.ajax` data is set and the `$('#content')` is from the loaded HTML from the `$.ajax` request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add a wrapper element via jQuery and then you can attach a scroll event.

```
$("#container").wrap('<div id="wrapper"></div>');

$("#wrapper").on('scroll', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```